# How to make a vpn connection using code on Android?

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn

how to write some code on Android phone using java or some other language to connect a vpn account?

i know the it's a PPTP vpn that i'm going to connect,and i have account name and password. i also could set it right via my HTC Desire.

but,i really want to write some code in order to use it in my own apk file,so please anyone help me on this?

**it's been two days and nobody answer my question? or just some kind of direction to follow?**

Comment: Start by getting access to the hidden API of Android - if you want this to work prior to ICS. http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/ This is the easy part.